# Unable to submit form even when input is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on a simple form where I'm checking if the input is empty. If it is then it should stop the form submission but if its not then it will go ahead and submit the form.

Right now, when the input field is empty and I press the submit button, the error message is displayed. But if I type something on the input field and try to submit, the code inside the if block triggers again and the form doesn't submit.

Why would the code inside the if block trigger again when the input is not empty? Wouldn't it just skip the if statement altogether and submit the form?

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="name-search" > 

     <form action="/send" method="POST" >

         <input class="search_input" name="name" type="text">
         <button type="submit" class="search_icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            
         <p class="error-msg"></p>  
                    
      </form>

</div>
```

JS

```
const form            = $( '.name-search form' );
const formInputVal    = $( '.name-search form .search_input' ).val();
const formErrorMsg    = $( '.name-search form .error-msg' );

$( form ).submit( ( e ) => {

        if ( formInputVal === '' ) {

                $( formErrorMsg ).text( 'Input field can\'t be empty.' );
                return false;

        } 

        return true;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put the value in a variable, that's it, you do it once, the variable doesn't change when the value does, so instead, you need to get the value everytime:

```
const form            = $( '.name-search form' );
const formInput       = $( '.name-search form .search_input' );
const formErrorMsg    = $( '.name-search form .error-msg' );

$( form ).submit( ( e ) => {

        if ( formInput.val() === '' ) {

                $( formErrorMsg ).text( 'Input field can\'t be empty.' );
                return false;

        } 

        return true;

});
```